# Error while accessing ASP.net webservice using JQuery - JSONP

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services, jquery, jsonp

Please look at the code below and help me to figure out what am I doing wrong in my web service code. I want to set up an asp.net web service that can be consumed using an JSONP. I am using Jquery at client side to access the site. Even after setting up proper attributes my web service still emits xml due to which the aynch call fails.

Web Service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat= ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString=false, UseHttpGet=true)]
    public string HelloWorld(int id, string __callback) {
        return  __callback + "({message: 'Hello World'})";
    }

}
```

Web Service Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">test({message: 'Hello World'})</string>
```

Web.Config:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" 
        type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" 
        type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" 
        type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, 
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
        validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" 
        type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, 
            Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost:54404/jsonp/webservice.asmx/HelloWorld?id=2&__callback=?", //?jsonp=MatchSvcCallback
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {},
    //jsonp : "MatchSvcCallback",
    success: function(msg) {
    alert("Inside success callback function"); // not being called

    },
    error: function(xhr, msg){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    }

});
```

The js code works with an handler, but fails for the webservice due to xml response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is because jQuery doesn't set the `Content-Type` header in the HTTP request for HTTP GET's when using `$.ajax()`. It only gets sent if the request type is 'POST'. This seems to be the case for both `dataType: "jsonp"` and `dataType: "json"`.

I tried your example and watched the request/response exchange in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and sure enough I don't see `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8` being sent in the headers for HTTP GET requests. The header does get sent if using HTTP POST. I'm guessing the presence of this header is a cue for the ASP.NET web service plumbing to decide whether to return either a JSON or XML formatted response.

It seems you're not the only one with this problem, see the following article on the on Elegant Code website:

[Calling Remote ASP.NET Web Services from JQuery](http://elegantcode.com/2008/12/02/calling-remote-aspnet-web-services-from-jquery/)

The solution appears to be one of the following:

- Use a `HttpModule` to inject the `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8` header into the request stream as described in the article above.
- Use a `HttpHandler` for the endpoint as you explained you were doing prior to using an ASP.NET web service.
- Try Rick Strahl's page based approach
  in the following article (which
  is in effect a `HttpHandler` anyway): [JSONP for cross-site Callbacks](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/107136.aspx).

Comment: I fixed the content type problem with beforeSent method of the $.ajax, and I cross checked the request headers with firebug they are properly added.

Comment: I think i have to add a web service extension to change the response so that the callback method name is added to the response in order to resolve the "invalid label" error from jquery