# Cross domain WebService Call not returning expected result

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have hosted a web-service in let

`http://example1.com/webservice.asmx`

and want to call from

`http://example2.com`

i have Code of jQuery like in example2.com

```
GetData: function () {
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://example1.com/webservice.asmx/GetData",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { Date: '' },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            debugger;                
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("data");
        }
    });
  }
```

it hit url like

```
http://example1.com/webservice.asmx/GetData?callback=jQuery19106349606812515739_1396429620115&Date=&_=1396429620116
```

and it hit that url by using GET Method (From firebug). actually where is problem i am unable to find it.
it response data in XML format.
and also responsed data in XML Format but not get in success event .
but it work fine if i put same code on same domain.

Comment: did your webservice wrap the response with the callback? e.g `jQuery19106349606812515739_1396429620115({'iam':'the json response'});`?

Comment: no , i don't know from where jQuery19106349606812515739_1396429620115
is added to requested to service url.

Comment: Do you know what `dataType: "jsonp"` mean?

Answer (score 0):

For JSONP your response must be wrapped in a Javascript function. Jquery automatically adds a callback-parameter to the GET-URL if you set `dataType: "jsonp"`. This callback parameter is a random js function name, which your ajax request needs to revive the data cross origin.

To make it work you need to change your Webservice as the following:

1. change to JSON
2. wrap the response with the callback-parameter. For example in VB.NET:

   ```
   Dim returnVal=Request.Param("Callback") & "(" & jsonreturn & ");"
   Response.Write(returnVal)
   ```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884253/jsonp-asmx-web-service) for details to get it working with your asmx webservice. Alternative you can change your Webservice to [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This fix works for me with pure json call from JQuery. 
Enable HttpGet and Post from your web.config within system.web

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpSoap"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Afterwards, create a method in your Global.asax file to enable cross domain communication (vb.net)
'==========================EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall=================

```
Private Sub EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod = "OPTIONS" Then 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type") 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
    End If

End Sub

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall() 
End Sub
'==========================
```