# Ajax undefined error when calling ASMX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
<script src="json.js";/>
<script src = "jquery.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PopulateBlendSpecification() {


    var data = new Object();
    data.Message = "message";
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax({
        url: "Test.aspx/Test",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            var listItems = [];
            var blendSpecItems = JSON.parse(result.d);

            for (var key in blendSpecItems) {
                listItems.push('<option value="' + blendSpecItems[key].BlendSpecID + '">' + blendSpecItems[key].BlendName
                            + '</option>');
            }

            var lBox = $('select[id$=lbBlendSpecs]');
            $(lBox).append(listItems.join(''));
        }
    })
}
```

Test.aspx.cs

```
      [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public  static string  Test(string message)
    {
       return message;
    }
```

This works fine when I try this within one project.
However, when I move the webmethod into a separate prjoject within the same solution I get an ajax error:

```
Error in: http://localhost/Test/MyWebService/Test.asmx/Test
 error: undefined
 type: ajaxError
 readystate: 4
 status: 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Webmethod is case sensitive.In your code function is **public  static string  Test(string message)** in parameter message is in small letter and you have to pass **data.Message** M is capital so method is unable to find function in code side.

So if you change code like below your code will work fine

```
    [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Test(string Message)
    {
        return Message;
    }
```

Comment: I may have changed it in the post to get my point across. The example works ok, it fails when I move it to an ASMX service .

Answer (score 0):

> when I move the webmethod into a separate prjoect within the same solution

Did you move it into a web service project and trying to consume in a web project, if that's the case this error would happen due to Cross site scripting restrictions. If you still need to have them in separate project, you will have to use jsonp and return jsonp friendly response.

You can find more info about JSONP + ASMX @[JSONP & ASMX Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884253/jsonp-asmx-web-service).

Comment: Yes, and I tried that avenue, I will look into it again. Or I might just move to WCF, i can't believe this simple task is so difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

do you have this header [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] in your asmx file.

Comment: No, I took that out because that prevents jQuery to do ajax requests.

Comment: actually that is used to make script to knoe about those existing methods.So please add it and try.